# How to set tcp_nodelay in MultipeerConnectivity framework in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I am using MultipeerConnectivity framework of iOS 7 for message passing among multiple devices. Can I set TCP_NODELAY in MultipeerConnectivity framework so that message should pass with minimum lag.

Is there any other way so that a small message can be passed to other device with minimum lag, preferably less than 100 milliseconds.

I want minimum lag because I have to start an audio in two devices at the same time. And if there is more than 100 milliseconds lag then the lag in two audios is observable.

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is an option in MultiPeer Framework To send data with Non Reliable mode. It will send the data immediately without any delay. But there is no guarantee of delievrey.

I hope it should work.

Comment: I have already tried this, it improves delay but lag in two audios is still observable. It proves that message passing delay is still more than 100 milliseconds.

Comment: There is no system in this world which send s a message to other device with 0.0000000 delay, it may send with smallest/ not observable time but zero lag is not possible. You will have to think your own logic for this, Like you may take time as a base or something else, But message with zero lag is 100% impossible.

Comment: I am not saying that I want 0.000000 delay, I want delay with less than 100 milliseconds.

Comment: You should understand what i am trying to say. I want to say that message with less than 100 mili seconds of lag is not possible for every 100 out of 100 attempts. Hope you got it now???

Comment: It's possible, with time sync and delay to start audio.

Answer (score 3):

You have to start your audio in same time (in 0.2s for example), there will always be some delay, so you should sync clocks on both devices.

```
--------------------------------------------> Device #1
  |     /\                |              |
  | time |      then send |       audio  |
  | sync |      start     |       starts |
  |      |      time      |       here   |
  \/     |                \/             |
--------------------------------------------> Device #2
```

In this case they will start audio simultaneously.
Don't forget to save your ping while syncing time (time to start audio has to be bigger than ping).

**Pros:**

- your audio will start almost at the same time

**Cons:**

- there will be delay (you'll need some time ~equal to ping).